# How to create timed messages using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I want to create a vbs file that reminds me to  take a small break every 1 hour. It should open a new window with "Time for a small break" as message. I will run the script all the time. It just need to open a small message box after every 1 hour and close the message box after 30 seconds. I am wondering if i could use time instead of using a big loop. 
Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46056141/edit) and post what did you tried as code so far !

Comment: Just create a Windows Scheduled task to run the script every hour.  A batch-file is different from a vbscript.  If you want a vbscript then remove the batch-file tag from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try for this batch file that create a scheduled vbscript file to be executed every hour : ***Create_scheduled_Vbscript.bat***

```dos
@echo off
color 0A & Mode 80,5
Title Create a scheduled vbscript file to be executed every hour
set "VBSFilePath=c:\Msg.vbs"
set "TaskName=BreakTime"
:CreateVBSFile
(
    echo strText = "Time for a small break !"
    echo set ws=CreateObject("wscript.shell"^)
    echo ws.Popup strText,30,strText,vbInformation 
)>"%VBSFilePath%"
Rem 60 minutes = 1Hour
Call :Create_Schedule_Task 60 "%TaskName%" "%VBSFilePath%"
Rem Just to query the BreakTime TaskName
Schtasks /Query /TN "%TaskName%" | find /i "%TaskName%"
pause & exit
::***********************************************************************
:Create_Schedule_Task <Repeat_Task_Every(N)Minute> <TaskName> <FilePath>
Schtasks /create /SC minute /MO %1 /TN "%~2" /TR "%~3"
exit /b
::***********************************************************************
```

And if you want for any reason delete this `TaskName = BreakTime`

just execute this small batch file : ***Delete_Taskname.bat***

```dos
@echo off
set "TaskName=BreakTime"
SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "%TaskName%" /F
pause
```